# Changing section focus on button click in Foundation CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation CSS and need some help on the sections object. I have a tabbed section on my page

```
<div class="section-container tabs" data-section="tabs">
<section id="section1">
<p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Step 1</a></p>
<div class="content" data-section-content>
<input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
</section>

<section id="section2">
<div class="content" data-section-content>
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
</div>
</section>

What I am trying to do is have a next button on section1 that would take me to section 2 by using this

<button class="small button" id="next1" onclick="document.getElementById('section2').className ='active';document.getElementById('section1').style ='padding-top: 49px';document.getElementById('section1').className ='';document.getElementById('section1').style ='';"> Next </button>
```

This however is not working. What happens is that by clicking the button it takes me to section 2 for a brief section and then brings me back to section 1. Any help on how I can nail this.

Comment: Incomplete code to work with .. How abt CSS ?

Comment: some css will be great

Answer (score 0):

Few things are missing and others not understood.

You need to give the focus. with `focus()`; so it takes you there.

You cannot change `className` if your element has no `class attribute`. You need to create it first or leave it empty in html.

To change style via javascript, you need to call the rule and then give it a value. `element.style.paddingTop='49px';`

To set focus on something else than form element or links, you may add the attribute `tabindex="0"` to the element your want to catch focus state.

a few change to your code , so you can experiment some of the things i say. http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/pCikI

I wish you success in learning :)

Comment: tried this but its still not working.. `<button class="small button" id="next1" onclick="var mybt = document.getElementById('section2'); mybt.className ='active';mybt.style ='padding-top: 49px';var omybt = document.getElementById('section1');ombt.className ='';ombt.style ='';mybt.tabindex ='0'; mybt.focus();"> Next </button>` What am i doing wrong in this?

Comment: mybt.tabindex ='0'; mybt.style ='padding-top: 49px';ombt.style =''; All this is wrong. And the rest i cannot say it relays on your HTML code. I can just advise you to read that page and pick up some of the basic knowledge you need to start http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info